# Should distance between rings change if the straps are shorter?

Tags: home-exercise, rings

I've read that the standard distance between rings is 50cm but in gymnastics, rings are hung on long straps (ropes)?

In a home gym where you attach to your ceiling or hang from a pull-up bar to use for basic exercises (not ring routines), the drop might only be a couple of metres. Should the spacing be changed to compensate? I'm not sure what effect making them closer/further apart has.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. [Rings should be hung at approximately shoulder width](https://gmb.io/hanging-gymnastic-rings/). For the sake of standardization, the Olympics have set the width of 50 cm, but you can customize your own setup.

[The length of the straps essentially has to do with swinging for a muscle-up](https://www.crossfitinvictus.com/blog/ring-straps/).

> ### Long Ring Straps
>
> These allow for a longer and smoother swing with less immediate tension at the bottom of the swing. It is much easier to get a “bigger” swing on longer straps. Long straps feel more like driving a car that can get more distance on a tank of fuel, but starting and stopping are slower.
>
> ### Short Ring Straps
>
> These make swinging high more difficult, but an athlete can create more immediate speed in the swing due to more connectedness with the rig. Tension at the bottom of the swing will be more abrupt and jerky. Short straps are more like a sports car that is quick off the line and better handling but slow down quickly when off the throttle.

Comment: ok great. As I say I shall not be swinging - using for push-ups, dips, inverse-rows, etc just to engage more stabilisation.

Comment: Excellent. I will admit that rings are not equipment I use regularly, so my knowledge is secondhand. My understanding is that you want them about shoulder width so that you can keep the rings directly below (or above) the shoulders, which means that your effort is focused on the actual movement rather than compensating to keep the rings in place.

Comment: @SeanDuggan I train with rings regularly (twice a week) and am happy to inform you add that your secondhand knowledge is correct ;)